# Why is sudo not installed by default in Debian?

Tags: debian, sudo

I was reading a guide to [install some software](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) and came reading until this shocking statement:

> `sudo` is not installed on Debian by default. Make sure your system is up-to-date and install it.

As current Debian user, this is difficult to believe since from installation I'm able to use `sudo`. So, maybe it got installed when I selected not to create a password for the root account (rendering the root account disabled) or something is amiss here. Does Debian not include `sudo` (or it's variants) as installed by default?

If we go by what the [other answer says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90523/41104), `sudo` can be installed due APT/DPKG dependencies, which in some cases will ask tasksel/apt to install those too, but isn't included in the required or important list:

```
➜  ~  aptitude search ~prequired | grep sudo
➜  ~  aptitude search ~pimportant | grep sudo
➜  ~  aptitude why '~prequired' sudo      
i A dpkg     Suggests   apt                             
i A apt      Suggests   aptitude | synaptic | wajig     
i A synaptic Recommends gksu | kdebase-bin | policykit-1
i A gksu     Depends    sudo                            
➜  ~  aptitude why '~pimportant' sudo           
i A apt      Suggests   aptitude | synaptic | wajig     
i A synaptic Recommends gksu | kdebase-bin | policykit-1
i A gksu     Depends    sudo
```

Comment: Keep in mind that even if `sudo` is not installed, you can still use the `su` command.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is a side-effect of installation parameters. If you specify a root password during installation sudo is not installed by default. If you do not specify a root password, `sudo` is installed. The authoritative source for this quoted below. Another related special case is that during install if you specify the `sudo-ldap` package, `sudo` will not be installed. This is the only time that `sudo-ldap` can be installed without a root password. If you wish to upgrade from `sudo` to `sudo-ldap` latter, you must have a root password during the upgrade.

> If you do not specify a password for the `root` user this account will
>   be disabled but the `sudo` package will be installed later to enable
>   administrative tasks to be carried out on the new system. -- from
>   debian-installer/manual/en/howto/installation-howto.xml

Comment: or you could chroot from a live cd and do the upgrade. or `sudo -i`.

Comment: Nope, dosn't work. When apt tries to install sudo-ldap or upgrade sudo to sudo-ldap, becouse sudo and sudo-ldap conflict it first uninstalls sudo before installing sudo-ldap and sudo's uninstall scripts fail unless a root password is defined. This is not hard to get around, just make sure root has a password while doing this, and then remove it.

Comment: Here is a nice guide to adding SUDO:  https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18063/debian-8-1-0-jessie-sudo-fix-not-installed-by-default

Comment: Installation Guide link where this is mentioned: https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apas03.html.en

Comment: The setup is performed by `user-setup-ask` and `user-setup-apply` in [`user-setup`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/d-i/user-setup.git/tree/).