# understanding LAMP: linux apache mysql and php

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I have multiple questions and I am confused.

Few months back, I was installing a software locally `~/bin`. Tools got installed successfully and running fine till date.
In installation it automatically created `var/www/` and added its folders in `~/bin`.

Now, I am trying to learn some  php development. I have installed apache from source, locally on `~/someFolder`, installation is complete. I did `sudo ~/someFoler/bin ./apachetl start`; `localhost` on browser, and `It works` message received on browser.

I do not want to use `sudo`,  and do all my learning experiments in `/usr/local` or `/usr/var/www`. Sorry, I do not understand well these directories.

From what all I have read and gone through, most users work in `/usr/var` or `usr/local`. However, while copying, removing or doing anything it requires `sudo`.

What is the work around for this?

How do I get Apache and PHP working locally without using too many `sudo` commands?

I read port 80 is required to start the server. Hence, `sudo` is necessary while starting the server.

Any help in these would be highly appreciated.

machine specification: Linux 3.11.0-15-generic x86_64

Ubuntu 13.10

**Edited**

If I install apache and php by sudo, would I have to move my web pages to `/var/www` location?

Comment: there are a bunch of things wrong with this post. first, try to use exact paths: I have no idea where `var/www/` is because I don't know where your current directory is. is it in your home folder? the root? be specific. also, why don't you like `sudo`? I don't see anything wrong with using Ubuntu's Apache packages. why in the world are you building everything yourself?

Comment: "I have multiple questions and I am confused." : Yup, so are we :) Please break this post into separate questions. Take each of the questions here and post them as a separate question. This site works by giving specific answers that solve specific problems, it doesn't work well when there are multiple issues combined in a single post. And everything that @strugee said as well.

Comment: sudo's builtin for a reason =)

Comment: @evamvid sudo most certainly is _not_ a builtin. It is a separate binary and is not even installed by default on most systems (including, believe it or not, [Debian itself](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106529/22222)).

Comment: @terdon whoops! My Bad...howbout "sudo's _there_ for a reason"?

Comment: Could OP just use `pkexec` instead of `sudo`?

Comment: @strugee: 
Thank you for your reply. I do not see anything wrong in builtin packages. I have had some issues after installing built in packages of mysql, hence I do not want to play around with them any more.
Second, I like trouble shooting from source code installation, if I wouldn't have done that, then probably I wouldn't have come to know port 80 is required for website. :)

I am fine with installing with sudo, but I do not want to use `sudo` thereafter.

Comment: @DeathMetal yes, but _why_ don't you want to use `sudo` afterward? your insistence on avoiding it just doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @strugee. :) I do not want to have all the power with sudo and knowingly, unknowingly disrupt files sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Built-in Webserver

If your goal is to learn PHP I highly recommend you use PHP's [built in webserver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), available on PHP version 5.4 and up.

```
cd ~/mywebsite
php -S localhost:8080
```

You now have a webserver, tied to the ~/mywebsite directory, and accessible in the browser at

```
http://localhost:8080
```

This all runs in user mode so you don't need to `sudo` anything.

---

## VHost solution

Even if you use the Apache method of serving up files, you can create a directory like ~/mywebsite and then create a [VirtualHost entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083681/apache-virtual-host-configuration) that points to that location. Then all the files there can be edited normally by your username. Note: the VirtualHost root cannot use tilde (~), it has to be absolute like `/home/johndoe/mywebsite`

Comment: One more tip: you can add a line to your /etc/hosts file to setup nicer domain names instead of "localhost". Add a line such as `127.0.0.1    widgets.local` and then you can use `http://widgets.local` in the browser.

Comment: So, my apache installed locally can work same as `sudo`?
I will need more help to understand this. Where do I create this `VirtualHost entry` ?

Comment: @terdon
I completely understand, I have to be particular while asking the question, but Apache and php are a bundle. I do not quite understand what has to be present in `/var`? If I install php and apache with `sudo` would I continue to use `sudo` to move files?
Do my files have to be present in `/var/www`?

Comment: You can add the `<VirtualHost>` block anywhere in the apache configuration file. If you installed it as a user, I'm not sure where it is, but you can try `find . | grep conf` to find it in your home directory.