# 'sudo' is not installed, I can't install it, and it asks if I am root

Tags: debian, software-installation, sudo, root

I just finished installing Debian 8 (Jessie) and tried to make a directory in `lib/firmware`, because there was a file missing (`rtl8723befw.bin`) in the installation, and it says

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `rtlwifi`: Permission denied
```

I tried putting sudo on the front, but then it returns:

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

When trying to install sudo with `apt-get install sudo` or even `apt-get update` it returns:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I am really at a loss of what to do. All the solutions that I seem to find for the latest error is to use sudo, but I don't even have that.

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106529/why-is-sudo-not-installed-by-default-in-debian

Comment: I never even use `sudo`. Always `su -c`.

Comment: Why did you try to use sudo if you set the root password?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you do not have `sudo` installed, you will need to actually become root.  Use `su -` and provide the root user's password (not *your* password) when asked.  Once you have become root, you can then `apt-get install sudo`, log out of the root shell, and actually use `sudo` as you are trying to, now that it will have been installed.

Comment: When making sudo `mkdir rtlwifi` it returns `mariel is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
`

Comment: cant edit but the sudo is part of the first code obviously

Comment: Become `root` again, and add yourself to the `wheel` group.  Also use `visudo` to make sure that the configuration to allow anyone in the `wheel` group to use `sudo` is not commented out.

Comment: could you be more specific on how to write that on terminal please?

Comment: googled info and it appears there is no wheel group created, but in `visudo` there is some piece of code really similar to what the wheel one would look like `# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 
`. Do I need to create a wheel group? How do I add my user name to the sudo group?

Comment: The `sudo` group serves the same purpose.

Comment: adduser yourusername sudo   -  note that group membership really doesn't change until you completely log out of all sessions/logins

Comment: If you can log in as root, why not just install the firmware as root?  Forget sudo.

Comment: @ivanivan: it is enough to launch a new login shell to get the changes in effect (just for that session though).

Comment: @Carl Because if you do that, one day you'll not log out of the root account.  You'll be thinking of some other things.  You'll use the root account thinking it's one of your logins.  And you'll break something.  That's the whole point of `sudo`.

Comment: @progo - no, all login sessions must end first

Comment: @ivanivan: maybe `wheel` is a special case but usually a group gets activated right once I do a new login in my gentoo box.

Comment: @progo Probably you are using a FreeBSD-based distribution. Debian isn't based in FreeBSD, which may explain the difference.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: or maybe it's systemd that is once again doing things difficult for you folks. In Gentoo it's still optional

Answer (score 17):

Become root, run `su`, give your root password, and then run:

```
apt install sudo
```

To grant administrative privileges to `Mariel`, run `visudo` command as root, and then edit your file as follows:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
Mariel  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Log in as user Mariel. You will be able to run sudo without problems.

Comment: This is what I would do also.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to given answers, if you do not know the root password to allow you to use `su`, you can boot to single user mode.

At the grub menu, press `e` to edit the boot command line.  Near the end of the line beginning `linux` add the word `single`, and continue the boot.  You will be placed at a root prompt and can reset the root password so that you can use `su` on the next normal boot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `su -c` as a quick and dirty replacement. If your `su` doesn't include `-c`, then just `su` to login as root. If you're working on some sort of odd embedded device that doesn't have `su`, try `login root` instead.