# How does on enable Laptop task on Debian

Tags: linux, laptop, debian-installer

I am fresh installing Debian on my laptop and I am having a little bit of trouble with the installer, from reading this link about ["What packages are installed by default in Debian?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90523/what-packages-are-installed-by-default-in-debian-is-there-a-term-for-that-set), I understand that the laptop task may contain features I may need.
But on my Debian installer (Both netinst and DVD.ISO) there is no option for this task and was wondering how can I get this to appear, Do I need a different iso e.g CD.ISO?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Netinstall. Choose Laptop and Standard system.

[image: The netinstall should have the option]

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you wouldn't need to worry about installing `task-laptop` in the installer.

All you need is a root login / `sudo` access on the installed system.  Then you can run the `tasksel` command to install selected tasks, from available package sources (as configured in the installer).  Most of the tasks are relatively small, apart from Desktop and perhaps Web Server.

New in recent versions of Debian (I think coinciding with the use of metapackages like `task-laptop`): you can also remove tasks if you decide you didn't need them, and it will more-or-less work.  (Previously it ended up removing too many packages).